# positioning in html?

Tags: html, css, positioning

How can I position [this](http://i1081.photobucket.com/albums/j359/hetsig/test2-2_zps4d6d9b4a.png) L-shaped container on my site so it looks like [this](http://i1081.photobucket.com/albums/j359/hetsig/testest_zps6876a446.png)?

I know pretty much nothing when it comes to webdesign or code, I managed to make the container with some help here and was able to put the 2 images in it but I feel completly lost when it comes to positioning it right.

My html for my site

```
<!--==============================content================================-->
<section id="content">
<div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_9" style="width:900px;">
        <h2>Etvab luxury estates</h2>
        <div class="line-1">
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width:410px;">
            <p>
                &nbsp;<br>
            </p>
            <p>
                Etvab luxury estates är en webportal för den kräsne bostadsköparen. Här har vi samlat ett representativt urval av de mest exklusiva bostäderna på Spaniens södra kust. Bostäder med unika lägen – havsnära eller örnnästen. Bostäder med förfinad design. Bostäder med vyer som är ”breathtaking”. Bostäder med luft och ytor som andas välbefinnande. Bostäder som har allti modern utrustning och senaste teknologi. Vi har medvetet lagt ribban högt, för att kittla fantasin, ge en svindlande resa i tid och rum och visa det bästa av spansk modern arkitektur. Vi har i första hand valt bostäder med lägen och kvalitet som är i absolut topskikt. Vi har inte tittat på status i områden då vi bedömer att det inte avgör bostadens värde och attraktion. Vår ambition är att förnya dessa sidor regelbundet, till nöje och nytta för den som söker inspiration till ett husköp med högsta kvalitet och läge. Men även för den som njuter av design och vackra miljöer - på avstånd.
            </div>
            <p>
                &nbsp;<br>
            </p>
            <style>
        .qs_input { height:40px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 8px; background: #f3f3f3; border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; border-bottom: 2px solid #d7d6d6; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; font-size: 1.0 em;}
        .the_table {font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; font-size: 0.8em;}
        .fastighet { padding:5px;}
        .inne { padding:8px 0px 8px 8px;  height:15px;}
            </style>
            <div id='qsResale' class='qs_body' style='width:50%; float:right; margin-left: 15px; padding:0px; margin: 0px;'>
                <form name='qsFormResale' id='qsFormResale' method='post' action='search.php'>
                    <table class="the_table" style='width:98%; float:left;'>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='qs_label' style='width:98%;'>
                            <h7>Typ av fastighet</h7>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select class='qs_input fastighet' name='Type' id='Type' style='width:90%;'>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='No Preference'></option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='S'>Studio</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='A'>Lägenhet</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='T'>Radhus</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='V'>Villa</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='P'>Tomt</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='C'>Kommersiella</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='AS'>Lägenhet & Studio</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='AT'>Lägenhet & radhus</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='AV'>Lägenhet & villa</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='TV'>Radhus & villa</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='qs_label' style='vertical-align:top;'>
                            <h7>Kust</h7>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select class='qs_input fastighet' name="Area" id="Area" onchange="cambia(this, document.qsFormResale.Location);" style='width:90%;'>
                                <option value='Costa de la Luz'>Costa de la Luz</option>
                                <option value='Costa del Sol'>Costa del Sol</option>
                                <option value='Costa del Sol East'>Costa del Sol East</option>
                                <option value='Granada (Costa Tropical)'>Granada (Costa Tropical)</option>
                                <option value='Almería (Costa Almería)'>Almería (Costa Almería)</option>
                                <option value='Murcia (Costa Calida)'>Murcia (Costa Calida)</option>
                                <option value='Alicante (Costa Blanca)'>Alicante (Costa Blanca)</option>
                                <option value='Costa Azahar'>Costa Azahar</option>
                                <option value='Costa Brava'>Costa Brava</option>
                                <option value='Costa Dorada'>Costa Dorada</option>
                                <option value='Ibiza'>Ibiza</option>
                                <option value='Cordoba'>Cordoba</option>
                                <option value='Tenerife'>Tenerife</option>
                                <option value='Mallorca'>Mallorca</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='qs_label' style='vertical-align:top;'>
                            <h7>Område</h7>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select class='qs_input' size='5' style="height:150px; width:395px;" name='Location' id='Location' multiple='multiple' style='width:90%;'>
                                <option class='qs_input inne' value='No Preference'>Ingen Preferens</option>
                                <option class='qs_input inne' value='Ayamonte'>Ayamonte</option>
                                <option class='qs_input inne' value='Huelva'>Huelva</option>
                                <option class='qs_input inne' value='Sanlucar de Barrameda'>Sanlucar de Barrameda</option>
                                <option class='qs_input inne' value='Tarifa'>Tarifa</option>
                                <option class='qs_input inne' value='Jimena de la Frontera'>Jimena de la Frontera</option>
                                <option class='qs_input inne' value='San Pablo de Buceite'>San Pablo de Buceite</option>
                                <option class='qs_input inne' value='Jerez de la Frontera'>Jerez de la Frontera</option>
                                <option class='qs_input inne' value='Cadiz'>Cádiz</option>
                                <option class='qs_input inne' value='Olvera'>Olvera</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='qs_label'>
                            <h7>Sovrum</h7>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select size='1' class='qs_input fastighet' name='Beds' id='Beds' style='width:90%;'>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='No Preference'>Ingen Preferens</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='1'>1 Bädd</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='1x'>1 Bädd eller fler</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='2'>2 Bäddar</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='2x'>2 Bäddar eller fler</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='3'>3 Bäddar</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='3x'>3 Bäddar eller fler</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='4'>4 Bäddar</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='4x'>4 Bäddar eller fler</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='5'>5 Bäddar</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='5x'>5 Bäddar eller fler</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='6'>6 Bäddar</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='6x'>6 Bäddar eller fler</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='7'>7 Bäddar</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='7x'>7 Bäddar eller fler</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='8'>8 Bäddar</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='8x'>8 Bäddar eller fler</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='9'>9 Bäddar</option>
                                <option class='qs_input' value='9x'>9 Bäddar eller fler</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='qs_label'>
                            <h7>Pris från</h7>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                <input type='text' class='qs_input' id='PriceMin' name='PriceMin' style='width:80%;' value='0' maxlength='8' onchange='return f_checkNumber(this,0,0);'>
                                &nbsp;<span class='qs_text'>&euro;</span>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='qs_label'>
                            <h7>Pris upp till</h7>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type='text' class='qs_input' id='PriceMax' name='PriceMax' style='width:80%;' value='0' maxlength='8' onchange='return f_checkNumber(this,0,0);'>&nbsp;<span class='qs_text'>&euro;</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='qs_label'>
                            <h7>Referens nr</h7>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style='padding-right:5%;'>
                            <input type='text' class='qs_input' id='RefNum' name='RefNum' value='' maxlength='12'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style='padding-top:10px;'>
                            <input type='submit' input type='button' class="button-5" value="Sök">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    <input type='hidden' name='P1' id='P1' value='ETvabResales'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='P2' id='P2' value='R'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='P3' id='P3' value='ALL'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='QS' id='QS' value='RESALE'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='Country' id='Country' value='Spain'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='RentalType' id='RentalType' value=''>
                    <input type='hidden' name='RentalDateFrom' id='RentalDateFrom' value='06-02-2013'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='RentalDateTo' id='RentalDateTo' value='06-02-2013'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='Language' id='Language' value='8'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='CustomArea' id='CustomArea' value=''>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
    </section>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
    <!--==============================footer=================================-->
    <footer>
    <div class="container_12">
        <div class="grid_12">
            <div class="line-2">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_2">
            <p>
                &nbsp;
            </p>
            <h5>Kontor Stockholm: </h5>
            <h5>Kontor Marbella:</h5>
            <h5>E-mail:</h5>
            <ul class="list1">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_2">
            <p>
                &nbsp;
            </p>
            <h5>+46 8 966 545</h5>
            <h5>+34 951087873</h5>
            <h5>Info@etvab.nu</h5>
            <ul class="list1">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_2">
            <h3 class="marg6"></h3>
            <ul class="list1">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_2">
            <p>
                &nbsp;
            </p>
            <h5>&nbsp;</h5>
            <p>
                &nbsp;
            </p>
            <ul class="list1">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_4">
            <p class="foot-text">
                Etvab luxury estates © 2012 <a href="index-6.html"></a>&nbsp;
                <!-- {%FOOTER_LINK} -->
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Html for the images

```
<div class="container-3">
  <div class="top"><img src="Images/bildlyx2.jpg" height="626" class="img1" />
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
  <img  src="Images/bildlyx1.jpg" width="202" height="210" class="img5" />
</div>
</div>
```

CSS for the images and container

```
.img1{
    top: 1px;
    left: -1px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    width: 452px;
    height: 660px;
}

.img5{
    top: 439px;
    right: 42px;
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    width: 574px;
    height: 230px;
}

.container-3{    
  position:relative; 
}

.top{
    width: 459px;
    height: 800px;
    border-bottom: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
} 

.bottom{
  z-index:2;
  width: 1100px;
  height: 250px;
  position:absolute;
  top:600px;
  left:0;
}
```

Comment: -1 For the question, because it's a fairly broad problem. Any reason you can't save all the images into one larger composite image and position the larger one as a background?

Comment: How would I do that? As I said in the post I barely know anything about building a website. I hired a web designer to do my site and now I cant get a hold of him so Im trying to fix this myself.

Comment: Open a graphics program, lay all the images out how you want and save it to a JPEG. Then put `background-image:url(imagename.jpg)` in the CSS. It's dirty, but it will do the job until you can get hold of the designer.

Answer (score 0):

DIVs are rectangle by nature and can not be an "L" shape. Since you are already using absolute positioning, just position your images and leave room for the form. Then set the z-index for the form and absolute position it on top of your image container.

Comment: Hm where change the positioning for the form? Thought it was something that was done in css/style but cant find it there.